# Data manipulation : How can I append path from my data array?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path

I want to append paths to a d3.selection. So I use `selection.data()` to bind the data to the new elements. No problem with that. My data is an array of object, with a key named 'points, which is an array of [x, y] coordinates.
I can draw circles because circle need only one point (of course) but as soon as I go for path, where more than one point is needed, I don't know how to do. Because the data() returns only one point. I need a way to get the previous data()

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-drag.v1.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-ease.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-timer.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-transition.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-zoom.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-polygon.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

<script src="init.js"></script>
<script src="drawIt.js"></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
<script src="polygons.js"></script>
</body>
```

polygons.js

```
blocks = [
    { name: 'chambre', x: 0, y: 0, points: [[0,0], [100,100], [245, 45], [63,55]] },
    { name: 'salon', x: 0, y: 0, points: [[50,50], [150,150], [255, 455], [63,555]] },
  ];

  drag = d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      d.x = d3.event.x;
      d.y = d3.event.y;
      draw();
    });

  function draw() {
    console.log(this)
    g = plan.selectAll("g")
      .data(blocks);

    room = g.enter().append("g")
      .call(drag);

    g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });

    room.append("polygon")
        .attr("points",function(d) { 
            return d.points.map(function(d) {
                return [d[0],d[1]].join(",")
            }).join(" ")
        })
      .attr("fill", "pink")
      .attr('stroke', 'black')

    room.selectAll('path')
        .data(blocks => blocks.points)
        .enter()
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d => d[0])
        .attr('cy', d => d[1])
        .attr('r', 3)
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr('stroke-width', 5)
    }

  draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need 2 things:

- A line generator;
- Passing the whole `points` array as the data of each `<path>`.

Since you have an array of arrays, not objects, the line generator can be as simple as:

```
const lineGenerator = d3.line();
```

Also, for the `data` method, we can put all `points` array inside a single array:

```
blocks.map(d=>d.points)
```

Here is the demo using your data:

```js
const blocks = [
    { name: 'chambre', x: 0, y: 0, points: [[0,0], [100,100], [245, 45], [63,55]] },
    { name: 'salon', x: 0, y: 0, points: [[50,50], [150,150], [255, 455], [63,555]] },
  ];
  
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const lineGenerator = d3.line();

const lines = svg.selectAll(null)
 .data(blocks.map(d=>d.points))
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator);
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="600"></svg>
```

Have in mind that, for a proper line chart, the data array must be **sorted**:

```js
const blocks = [
    { name: 'chambre', x: 0, y: 0, points: [[0,0], [100,100], [245, 45], [63,55]] },
    { name: 'salon', x: 0, y: 0, points: [[50,50], [150,150], [255, 455], [63,555]] },
  ];
  
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const lineGenerator = d3.line();

const lines = svg.selectAll(null)
 .data(blocks.map(d=>d.points.sort((a,b)=> a[0] - b[0])))
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator)
  .style("stroke", (_,i)=> i ? "red" : "blue")
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer. What I didn't tell, is that I want my paths to be from point[i] to point[i+1], so make as much 2 points straight lines as my array contains points.

Comment: What made the trick for me is to reduce my data to get an array of two points array by element. But your approche seems to be more in the clean d3 way of doing things

Comment: like so ... `room.selectAll('path')
        .data(blocks => blocks.points.reduce((array, current, i) => {
            array[i] = [current]
            if (i-1 >= 0) {
                array[i-1].push(current)
            }
            if (i == blocks.points.length-1) {
                array[i].push(blocks.points[0])
            }
            return array
        },[]))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', d => `M${d[0][0]} ${d[0][1]} L${d[1][0]} ${d[1][1]}`)
        .attr('stroke', 'yellow')
        .attr('stroke-width', 5)`